# How to successfully deploy Nuxtjs & firebase app to vercel?

Tags: deployment, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I've very simple `nuxtjs & firebase` application with only two pages, I've imported the `github repo` into my vercel account, but when I try to deply I keep getting this message `Error: The Serverless Function "index" is 50.5mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb. Learn More: https://vercel.link/serverless-function-size`.

I don't know how I can fix this issue.

My nuxtjs config as below

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const useEmulators = false; // manually change if emulators needed
export default {
  target: 'static',
  ssr: false,
  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [{ src: "~plugins/mixins.js" }],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  router: {
    middleware: [],
  },

  // for api endpoints
  serverMiddleware: [],
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [],
  buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/firebase", "@nuxtjs/date-fns"],
  firebase: {
    lazy: false,
    onFirebaseHosting: false,
    terminateDatabasesAfterGenerate: true,
    config: {
      apiKey: "xxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxx",
      projectId: "xxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
      appId: "xxxx",
      measurementId: "xxxx",
    },
    services: {
      auth: false,
      firestore: {
        // emulatorPort:
        //   process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? 8080 : undefined,
        // emulatorHost: "localhost",
        memoryOnly: false, // default
        enablePersistence: true,
        emulatorPort: isDev && useEmulators ? 8080 : undefined,
      },
      storage: {
        emulatorPort: isDev && useEmulators ? 9199 : undefined,
        emulatorHost: "localhost",
      },
    },
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    loaders: {
      sass: {
        implementation: require("sass"),
      },
      scss: {
        implementation: require("sass"),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

My vercel.json file

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder@0.22.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "el-gam3a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "deploy": "push-dir --dir=dist --branch=master --cleanup"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/date-fns": "^1.5.0",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^8.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder": "0.22.1",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "firebase": "9.6.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "push-dir": "^0.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.8",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
  }
}
```

I've followed [Nuxtjs docs](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/vercel/) for deploying nuxtjs app to vercel, but nothing changed.

Comment: which packages do you have in your project ? can you post your `package.json` contents ? you might have some packages that you don't need

Comment: @Jimmar thanks for replying, I've updated the question with my package.json file, can you have a look ?